# Editing shortcut (.lnk) properties with Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, shortcut

I've found a nasty VBS way to do this, but I'm looking for a native PoSh procedure to edit the properties of a .LNK file.  The goal is to reach out to remote machines, duplicate an existing shortcut with most of the correct properties, and edit a couple of them.

If it would just be easier to write a new shortcut file, that would work too.

Comment: also see powershell docs: [creating-a-desktop-shortcut-with-wscriptshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-7.4#creating-a-desktop-shortcut-with-wscriptshell) and [create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
Copy-Item $sourcepath $destination  ## Get the lnk we want to use as a template
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($destination)  ## Open the lnk
$shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\path\to\new\exe.exe"  ## Make changes
$shortcut.Description = "Our new link"  ## This is the "Comment" field
$shortcut.Save()  ## Save
```

Found the VB version of the code here:
http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Extract-the-target-file-from-a-shortcut-file-.lnk/18349

Comment: FYI. This Solution works fine for local files, it doesn't work for UNC paths.

Comment: I did some tests and this works fine for UNC paths.  I'm not sure what @iraSenthil tested.

Comment: I'm not sure why that code wouldn't work for UNC paths, I've done the same thing for years in VB-Script/JScript. Just have to have permission and access to make the change (see example paths in note on Marco Shaws posting). As for Powershell, Tobias has put everything into two nice functions, get-shortcut and set-shortcut. Found here: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7895.aspx

Comment: Worked brilliantly for me. Another couple of useful attributes are $shortcut.Arguments and $shortcut.WorkingDirectory. Also worked perfectly for UNC paths

Comment: Here's some documentation with examples of each property in use: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_create_shortcut.htm.

Comment: iraSenthil possibly ran the script as a user who had UNC path restricted via Group Policy. That's the only reason I can think for it to fail.

Comment: The PowerShell.com link above has rotted, but Tim Lewis's answer (currently below) has code derived from that page that is very, very useful.

Comment: The PowerShell.com page has been preserved at https://web.archive.org/web/20160421140910/http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7895.aspx .

Answer (score 32):

Below are the functions I use for dealing with .lnk files. They are modified versions of the functions found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141018183948/http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7895.aspx) as mentioned by @Nathan Hartley. I've improved `Get-Shortcut` to handle wildcards like `*` by passing strings to `dir` to expand them into sets of FileInfo objects.

```
function Get-Shortcut {
  param(
    $path = $null
  )
  
  $obj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

  if ($path -eq $null) {
    $pathUser = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('StartMenu')
    $pathCommon = $obj.SpecialFolders.Item('AllUsersStartMenu')
    $path = dir $pathUser, $pathCommon -Filter *.lnk -Recurse 
  }
  if ($path -is [string]) {
    $path = dir $path -Filter *.lnk
  }
  $path | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -is [string]) {
      $_ = dir $_ -Filter *.lnk
    }
    if ($_) {
      $link = $obj.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)

      $info = @{}
      $info.Hotkey = $link.Hotkey
      $info.TargetPath = $link.TargetPath
      $info.LinkPath = $link.FullName
      $info.Arguments = $link.Arguments
      $info.Target = try {Split-Path $info.TargetPath -Leaf } catch { 'n/a'}
      $info.Link = try { Split-Path $info.LinkPath -Leaf } catch { 'n/a'}
      $info.WindowStyle = $link.WindowStyle
      $info.IconLocation = $link.IconLocation

      New-Object PSObject -Property $info
    }
  }
}

function Set-Shortcut {
  param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  $LinkPath,
  $Hotkey,
  $IconLocation,
  $Arguments,
  $TargetPath
  )
  begin {
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  }
  
  process {
    $link = $shell.CreateShortcut($LinkPath)

    $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
      Where-Object { $_.key -ne 'LinkPath' } |
      ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }
    $link.Save()
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that these functions are wonderful, and I appreciate you posting them. They just saved me a ton of hassle in a Robocopy job.

Comment: If you're getting blank properties like .TargetPath, be aware that CreateShortcut() needs the full UNC path to your .LNK file.  It ignores the current directory and ".\myshortcut.lnk" fails too.  You don't get an error, just empty properties.

Answer (score 4):

A short addition to @JasonMArcher's answer..

To see available properties you can just run `$shortcut` after `$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($destination)` in a *PS*.
This will print all properties and their current values.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a native way.

There is this DOS util: [Shortcut.exe](http://www.optimumx.com/download/Shortcut.zip).

You still need to copy the util to the remote system, then possibly call it using WMI to make the changes you're looking for.

I'm thinking the easier way will be to overwrite and/or create a new file.

Do you have access to these systems via a remote share?

Comment: Hi Marco.  Sure, I can access them via a remote share.

Comment: Well, I don't do enough regular admin stuff like this, but I'm thinking you can simply use the share to update the lnk file remotely.

Comment: Remotely, you would use something like "\\$Computer\C$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\The Shortcut.lnk" for 95/98/XP/2003 and "\\$Computer\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\The Shortcut.lnk" for Vista/Win 7/2008.