# How to get description of Desktop Icon in Windows via batch code?

Tags: batch-file

I need help form you guys,I want to know ,How can I get description of Desktop icon using batch code?
Thanks
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

not possible with pure batch.But you can try [tooltipinfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat) or [shortcutjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) . They are hybrid scripts that combine wsh/jscript/batch and should be saved with `.bat` extension.
Here's how you can use them:

```
tooltipinfo.bat "C:\Users\my\Desktop\Git Shell.lnk"
```

or

```
shortcutjs.bat -examine "C:\Users\my\Desktop\Git Shell.lnk"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke a PowerShell command to retrieve the info.  In a .bat script or in a cmd console,

```js
powershell "(new-object -COM wscript.shell).CreateShortcut('Word 2013.lnk').Description"
```

... would simply output the description stored in the "Word 2013" shortcut's comment field to the console.  (Don't worry: the `CreateShortcut` method doesn't overwrite your shortcut.  Think of it as creating space in memory for the shortcut object's retrieval.)

If you want to capture the description to a variable, use a `for /f` loop.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "lnk=Word 2013.lnk"

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell "(new-object -COM wscript.shell).CreateShortcut('%lnk%').Description"'
) do set "description=%%~I"

echo %description%
```

([Credit should go to Jason Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534409/1683264) for the idea.)