# Jupyter UTF-8 error when click a .lnk in Windows

Tags: python, utf-8, jupyter

When I [click the lnk in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnocA.png),I got a [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mbHR.png).

> Error! C:\Users\proalex\Desktop\Files.lnk is not UTF-8 encoded
>
> Saving disabled.
>
> See Console for more details.

How can I figure it out?

My OS is windows 10

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click the link?

Comment: I want go to the directory 'E:\Files' which is the lnk links with

Comment: Windows lnk files don't work in jupyter, and many other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that this is a stupid generic error message given by Jupyter.

What it means is ...  I have no idea how to display this kind of file

I also spent hours figuring this out when I was trying to open a .gz  file

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Klaus D. and @blissweb it's not possible to open a `.lnk` shortcut through the jupyter navigator, as it is basically a text file that can be interpreted by specific applications (such as File explorer). Instead if you want to see the files inside a `.lnk` shortcut you can start jupyter directly running the `jupyter notebook` command in a command prompt or windows-powershell that is already inside the shortcutted path. To achieve this you have three ways:

1. **Navigate through File explorer** directly into the shortcutted path, copy the path in a command prompt and then run `jupyter notebook` here
2. **Navigate through the command prompt** into the shortcutted path. To do this you can execute `type Files.lnk|find "\"` (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1338732/1463640)) that will print the shortcutted path by `.lnk`. Then you can copy this path, `cd` into it and then run `jupyter notebook` there
3. **Navigate through windows powershell** into the shortcutted path. To do this you can follow the passages in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762873/11764049), then `cd` into the `$target variable` and run `jupyter notebook`