# Is there any way to find out the remote share path owner and total space using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have list of remote sharepaths which i dont have direct access, I want to find out Owner of each share and total space . Is there any way to find it out using powershell script??

Thanks In advance
jerin

Comment: Shares don't have owners. And what exactly do you mean by "total space"? The total size of the files/folders under that share? The total diskspace provided by the file system? And most importantly: what have you tried so far to solve this yourself?

Comment: Shares do have owners.  Look under the advanced security permissions.  What do you mean you don't have direct access?

Comment: The 'owner' is a property of the file system directory, not the share itself.

Comment: @Kevin_ You're confusing NTFS permissions with share permissions. Folders have owners. Shares don't.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers eh, same thing. I believe thats what OP is referring to.

Comment: @Kevin_ Perhaps. But until the OP decides to clarify the question we won't know.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the owner of a folder works the same way regardless of whether it's a local folder or a share. Simply use UNC:

```
$path = <path_to_folder> # For example: \\server_name\share_name
Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner
```

It's not clear from your question whether you want to get *free space* on the volume where the folder is located or the total *size of all items* in the folder. Anyway:

Finding free space:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/04/08/using-powershell-v2-to-gather-info-on-free-space-on-the-volumes-of-your-remote-file-server.aspx

Finding the total size:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24091871/1751302) is a function to find total size.