# How to make Get-ChildItem not to follow links

Tags: powershell

I need `Get-ChildItem` to return all files/folders inside a path. But there are also symlinks going of to remote servers. The links are created by: `mklink /D link \\remote-server\folder`

If I run `Get-ChildItem -recurse` it follows the links to the remote servers and lists all files/folders from there. If I use -exclude it does not list the folder matching the excluded pattern but still goes down and lists all included files and folders.

What I actually need is `Get-ChildItem -recurse` to ignore links at all and not to follow them.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed the same thing myself.  Settled on...

```
Function Get-ChildItemNoFollowReparse
{
    [Cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName  = 'Path', Position = 0,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String[]] $Path
    ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName  = 'LiteralPath', Position = 0,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [String[]] $LiteralPath
    ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName  = 'Path')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName  = 'LiteralPath')]
        [Switch] $Recurse
    ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName  = 'Path')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName  = 'LiteralPath')]
        [Switch] $Force
    )
    Begin {
        [IO.FileAttributes] $private:lattr = 'ReparsePoint'
        [IO.FileAttributes] $private:dattr = 'Directory'
    }
    Process {
        $private:rpaths = switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
                              'Path'        { Resolve-Path -Path $Path }
                              'LiteralPath' { Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath }
                          }
        $rpaths | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path `
                | ForEach-Object {
                      Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -Force:$Force
                      if ($Recurse -and (($_.Attributes -band $lattr) -ne $lattr)) {
                          Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -Force:$Force `
                            | Where-Object { (($_.Attributes -band $dattr) -eq $dattr) -and `
                                             (($_.Attributes -band $lattr) -ne $lattr) } `
                            | Get-ChildItemNoFollowReparse -Recurse
                      }
                  }
    }
}
```

Will *print* all the child items of a path (including symlinkds/junctions) but will not *follow* symlinkds/junctions when recursing.

Didn't need all the features of `Get-ChildItem`, so didn't write them in, but if you only need `-Recurse` and/or `-Force`, this is mostly a drop-in replacement.

Tested (briefly) in PSv2 and PSv4 on Windows 7 and 2012.  No warranty, etc.

(PS: *Hate* `Verb-Noun` in these situations...)

Comment: elegant use of stream. Tested with PS 5.1 and this solution really exclude navigation of reparsePoint.

Comment: FYI, there's a typo in the function, as currently given in the answer. In your recursion, you're calling `Get-ChildItemNoFollow -Recurse` instead of `Get-ChildItemNoFollowReparse -Recurse`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Saved my day (or evening to be more specific)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do (Powershell 7):

```
get-childitem -recurse -attributes !reparsepoint
```

Well, this will exclude the link itself, but not files underneath it gotten with -recurse in Powershell 5.1.  Neither would

```
| where attributes -notmatch reparsepoint
```

Actually, it works as expected in powershell 7.

For PS 5 with the eccentric -exclude option:

```
get-childitem -exclude link | get-childitem -recurse
```

or with the same logic:

```
get-childitem -attributes !reparsepoint | get-childitem -recurse
```

Note that mklink is a cmd builtin.  You can use the cmd builtin "rmdir" to delete the symlink.  Using cmd's "del" would be catastrophic and delete the entire remote share after a prompt.

```
cmd /c mklink /D link \\remote-server\folder
cmd /c rmdir link
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Powershell 6.0, [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) has a `-FollowSymlink` switch. If not provided, it doesn't follow them.

> -FollowSymlink By default, the Get-ChildItem cmdlet displays symbolic links to directories found during recursion, but doesn't recurse into
> them. Use the FollowSymlink parameter to search the directories that
> target those symbolic links. The FollowSymlink is a dynamic parameter
> and is supported only in the FileSystem provider.
>
> This parameter was introduced in PowerShell 6.0.

Also, if you want to exclude symlinks entirely from the pipeline, they can be filtered out using the `LinkType` property, which won't be present on items that aren't symlinks.

```
Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | Where-Object LinkType -eq $null
```

Note the comment in the citation about the parameter only being supported by items from the `FileSystem` provider. If the remote path isn't of this variety, you can consider using [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2)  to associate it with a `FileSystem` provider drive, e.g.:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "Public" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Server01\Public"

Write-Host "The provider for 'Public:' is $((Get-Item 'Public:').PSProvider)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I was beginning to think that I would never be able to find an acceptable solution!

I found it! It is genius!

[Processing symbolic links and junctions safely in PowerShell](https://schneegans.de/windows/find-files/)

I didn't even check FilterByName and FilterByType. I won't use them.

With my own minor modifications to get the result out of the loop for post-processing:

```
function Find-Files
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Lists the contents of a directory. Unlike Get-ChildItem, this function does not recurse into symbolic links or junctions in order to avoid infinite loops.
    #>

    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        [string]
        # Specifies the path to the directory whose contents are to be listed. By default, the current working directory is used.
        $LiteralPath = (Get-Location),

        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        # Specifies a filter that is applied to each file or directory. Wildcards ? and * are supported.
        $Filter,

        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        [boolean]
        # Specifies if file objects should be returned. By default, all file system objects are returned.
        $File = $true,

        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        [boolean]
        # Specifies if directory objects should be returned. By default, all file system objects are returned.
        $Directory = $true,

        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        [boolean]
        # Specifies if reparse point objects should be returned. By default, all file system objects are returned.
        $ReparsePoint = $true,

        [Parameter( Mandatory=$false )]
        [boolean]
        # Specifies if the top directory should be returned. By default, all file system objects are returned.
        $Self = $true
    )
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$all = @()
    function Enumerate( [System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $Item ) {
        $null=$all.Add($Item);
        #$Item
        if ( $Item.GetType() -eq [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] -and ! $Item.Attributes.HasFlag( [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint ) ) {
            foreach ($ChildItem in $Item.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() ) {
                Enumerate $ChildItem;
            }
        }
    }

    function FilterByName {
        process {
            if ( ( $Filter -eq $null ) -or ( $_.Name -ilike $Filter ) ) {
                $_;
            }
        }
    }

    function FilterByType {
        process {
            if ( $_.GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo] ) {
                if ( $File ) { $_; }
            } elseif ( $_.Attributes.HasFlag( [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint ) ) {
                if ( $ReparsePoint ) { $_; }
            } else {
                if ( $Directory ) { $_; }
            }
        }
    }
    
    $Skip = if ($Self) { 0 } else { 1 };
    Enumerate ( Get-Item -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Force ) 
    return $all | Select-Object -Skip $Skip | FilterByName | FilterByType; # I didn't check if FilterByName and FilterByType in ok state.
}
$HomePath='C:\YourPath'
$fObject = Find-Files -LiteralPath $HomePath
$fObject|foreach{
    if($_.FullName -ne $HomePath){
        $_.FullName
    }
}
```