# Count number of folders in directory and ignore shortcuts

Tags: powershell, count

I have a script which will accurately tell me how many folders are in a directory, and the subdirectories within. However, for one directory which I am working with, there are shortcut folders which seem to cause the script to fail.

**Below is the error message which I receive:**

```
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Folder\SubFolder\folder1\jpos'.
At C:\Desktop\Script Files\fileCount.ps1:34 char:10
+ $items = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\SubFolder\ -Recurse
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Folder\SubFolder\folder1\jpos:String) [Get-ChildItem], 
DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`
```

The script runs fine for directories without shortcuts, but it seems to always fail when there are shortcuts within the directory.

**Below is the code snippet for this section:**

```
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\SubFolder -Recurse
$termFolder = ($items | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}).count
```

Is there any way to skip over shortcuts or a better way to do a folder count?

Comment: When you say shortcuts do you mean links? [This might be a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763790/how-to-make-get-childitem-not-to-follow-links). Look at the superuser question linked there as well

Comment: There is a `-Directory` switch to GCI.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Not in earlier PS versions. `where {$_.PSIsContainer}` serves the same.

Comment: The issue is [debated over here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3951) but that won't help you with your current PowerShell. [Doing recursion yourself](https://superuser.com/a/528499/639112) might be an option.

Comment: I agree with [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt), I could not reproduce the error taken the [debated over here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3951) in account. The error is probably caused by something within the specific folder that is linked (e.g.  access rights), so the question is: what happens when you do a `Get-ChildItem` on the actual folder that is linked? Anyhow, I guess that the solution lays also in the the debate or "Doing recursion yourself" [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) refers to.

Answer (score 0):

(gci path |?{$_.Extension -ne ".lnk"}).Count

Shortcuts have .lnk extension and gci means Get-Childitem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use -directory like this (for PowerShell 3 or +):

```
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\SubFolder -Recurse -Directory
$termFolder = $items.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the directory collection folder subsequently in script, then you can simply use

```
$countDirs = $(Get-ChildItem -path c:\folder\subfolder -Recurse -Directory).count
```