# How to make optional tools of Git For Windows 2.7 load customized configuration?

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I installed [Git For Windows 2.7.2](https://git-scm.com/download/win) a few days ago. Now I have some problems with using optional tools `Git For Windows` provides from `cmd.exe`. In the previous version of `Git For Windows`(or say `msysgit`), I could configure these tools by modifying `Git/etc/git-completion.bash`. For example:

```
alias ls='ls --show-control-chars --color=auto'
```

I used this way to make `ls` display file names that contained Chinese characters normally. Now it seems this way doesn't work. In fact there is no `git-completion.bash` under `Git/etc/`. There **is** a `git-completion.bash` under the folder `Git/mingw64/share/git/completion`. I tried to copy it to `Git/etc` and add the alias above, which didn't work either. These tools only works fine in `Git Bash`. So how should I configure these tools together with `git` to use them from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: There is a [duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/602872/how-do-i-modify-my-git-bash-profile-in-windows) of this question on superuser.

Comment: I tried both of the answers. Seems neither works for `Git 2.7.2`. Everything only works fine in `Git Bash`.

Comment: So you're looking to access these aliases from a Windows shell?

Comment: Yes, it's convenient if these aliases can be accessed from a Windows shell. In previous versions bashrc worked. But in Git 2.7.2 the configuration doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672272/msysgit-vs-git-for-windows) explains why you no longer have this functionality. In short, msysgit provided a unix shell emulator, mingw. Git for Windows is git compiled in a Windows environment.

Therefore, `ls` is simply an alias for `dir` in a Windows shell, not mingw's `ls`. If you want to create some Windows aliases, you can use `doskey`. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt) for that.

Alternatively, I would suggest that you just start using [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/mt173057.aspx), where you'll be able to set up the `$profile` variable with some powerful commands like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138144/what-s-in-your-powershell-profile-ps1-file).